# how to make an oval in css?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I want to make an oval like:

[image]

But when i used this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Oval</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .oval {
                width: 160px;
                height: 80px;
                background: #a84909;
                border-radius: 40px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="oval"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It gives me this:

[image]

To make a circle it works, but an oval not.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

All you have to do is to change `border-radius: 40px` to `border-radius: 50%`.

```css
.oval {
  width: 160px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #a84909;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="oval"></div>
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to set the border radius in percentage :

> Percentage : Denotes the size of the circle radius, or the semi-major and semi-minor axes of the ellipsis, using percentage
>   values. Percentages for the horizontal axis refer to the width of the
>   box, percentages for the vertical axis refer to the height of the box.
>   Negative values are invalid.

source : [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius#Values_2)

For a detailed explanation of why pixel values for border-radius can't output an oval shape see [Border-radius in percentage (%) and pixels (px)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966499/border-radius-in-percentage-and-pixels-px)

Example :

```
border-radius: 50%;
```

```css
 .oval {
   width: 160px;
   height: 80px;
   background: #a84909;
   border-radius: 50%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="oval"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use a percentage as border radius, like: `border-radius: 50%;`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
     .oval {
            width: 160px;
            height: 80px;
            background: #a84909;
            moz-border-radius: 80px / 40px;
            webkit-border-radius: 80px / 40px;
            border-radius: 80px / 40px;
            }
```

PS. I do not have the compiler in front of me so there may be some minor error.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Oval</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .oval {
                width: 160px;
                height: 80px;
                background: #a84909;
                border-radius: 50%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="oval"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

An other way of thinking is explained [here](http://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/).

Answer (score 1):

All the previous answers, He doesn't want a circle according to his question. He wants an Oval. This works but there is probably a better way.

```css
#oval{position:relative;background-color:green;width:20px;height:100px;  
  display:inline-block;z-index:100;
  }
#one{background-color:green; display:inline-block;width:200px;height:100px;border-radius:50%;position:relative;left:100px;}
#two{background-color:green; display:inline-block;width:200px;height:100px;border-radius:50%;position:relative;left:-100px;}
```

```html
<div id="one">&nbsp;</div><div id="oval">&nbsp;</div><div id="two">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.oval {
  width: 10px;/*change here*/
  height: 157px;/* or here if you want to be more sharper*/
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #1abc9c;
}
```

```html
<div class="oval"></div>
```

If you want more shapes, you can generate these using

```
http://enjoycss.com/code/
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.oval {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px/50px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="oval"></div>
```