# How to get a ovel shape by using html5, css3

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
 <title> Oval shape</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div style="width:400px; height:400px; background-color:#ff0;">Oval</div>

  <p> This is Oval shape by using html5, css3.</p>
 <body>
</html>
```

I written code like this ..i Want div tag as ovel shape..can you please tell me...

Comment: Please post the CSS you have tried so far..

Comment: i have written inline css in code...

Comment: Please check http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: yes i got it... thanks to all...

Comment: also see [how to make an oval in css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26961221/how-to-make-an-oval-in-css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

html

```
 <div id="oval">Oval</div> <p> This is Oval shape by using html5, css3.</p>
```

css

```
#oval {
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
background: red;
-moz-border-radius: 100px / 50px;
-webkit-border-radius: 100px / 50px;
border-radius: 100px / 50px;
}
```

see the below link

http://jsfiddle.net/Mithun146/b4k20ruw/

Comment: yes iam got it.. thakyou...

Comment: unfortunately this is *not* a responsive solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the border-radius to allow for dynamic sizes. I would also point out there isn't *really* a need for prefixes for this css:

```css
div{
  height:100px;
  width:200px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background-color: #ff0;
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
```