# How to set transparent borders using CSS around an image?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a oval type shape on hover when someone hovers over the links. By doing so I am loosing the image which is part of the link. I know I am doing something wrong but what?

```css
.pagelinks {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 48%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #828282;
}

.pagelinks a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.pagelinks a img:hover {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #828282;
  padding: 7px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 0.5px;
}
```

```html
<span class="pagelinks">
  <a href="{1}">
    <img src="../images/integration/FastLeft.jpg"/>
  </a>
  <a href="{2}">
    <img src="../images/integration/SlowLeft.jpg"/>
  </a>
  | Page {5} of {6} |
  <a href="{3}">
    <img src="../images/integration/SlowRight.jpg"/>
  </a>
  <a href="{4}">
  <img src="../images/integration/FastRight.jpg"/>
  </a>
</span>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ssadat/ckr8r9y2/)

Comment: That's not HTML, please post the generated HTML. Also, try being more explicit about your end goals. Are you attempting to make the image an oval, overlay an oval or something else?

Comment: Can you include the rendered html please, not whatever this template/framework code is?

Comment: Can you please make a working snippet? It would be easier to solve the problem. (You can make snippets directly in questions and answers, there's a button for it in the editor) Edit: wow I'm late.

Comment: And can you include a picture or something of your end goal? You're changing the `img` to `width:1px;height:0.5px` on hover so of course it's going to be tiny... not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to make an oval in css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26961221/how-to-make-an-oval-in-css)

Comment: @vinid. For God sake man. Read my question. I am saying my image is hiding behind the oval that I've made and you are making it duplicate. Come on remove it.

Comment: @Mike please try and help yourself by improving your question instead of complaining about a comment. Provide an [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Be more explicit about what you're trying to achieve. Sometimes a diagram goes a long ways. Right now some the end goal is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: @hungerstar: JSFiddle is available man, take a look.

Comment: @Mike last I checked it was empty. I'll check it again. FWIW I'd create a Stack Snippet so you have working code in your post. Also, it's still not clear what your end goal is. Why don't you want to clarify that point?

Comment: dude, it is working for me. When I click on the image it creates a shape of like oval ok and the image disappears. I want to see the image with the borders like an oval shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like **@Michael Cocker** said, you're setting the image size to basically nothing. Don't do that and possibly removed the padding. If you need it will shift on hover so maybe add it to the image prior to hover.

You mention oval but have a `border-radius` of `3px` which is not a lot so increase that as needed. Using `50%` will get you a circle if the image has equal height and width, otherwise it will be an oval.

```css
.pagelinks {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 48%;
  color: #828282;
}

.pagelinks a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.pagelinks img {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.pagelinks img:hover {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #828282;
}
```

```html
<span class="pagelinks">
  <a href="{1}">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30/fc0"/>
  </a>
  <a href="{2}">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30/fc0"/>
  </a>
  | Page {5} of {6} |
  <a href="{3}">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30/fc0"/>
  </a>
  <a href="{4}">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30/fc0"/>
  </a>
</span>
```

Comment: No problem. I'm mean to be overbearing with my suggestions in the comments above. Just trying to get clear and concise information and examples for all users of StackOverflow - those trying to answer and those that might find this post useful in the future.

Comment: The biggest problem is that people do not want to solve the problem therefore most of the time they don't even go over the question. Just by one word they mark the question duplicate. Anyways, thanks again.