# how to set div background an oval shape?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set my index page div an oval shape. 
I managed to do so with border-radius but the problem is that the edges are
too round and not as I expect.

**this is my expected result**

**link at the end of css**

```html
<div class="home-page"></div>
```

```
.home-page {
    z-index: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 14vh max-content 18vh; 
}

.home-page::before {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    height: 83vh;

    background-image: linear-gradient(215deg, #3f2b96, #a8c0ff);
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 75px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 75px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your expected result is broken

Comment: Hi. I fixed it => https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4F6X.jpg

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to make an oval in css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26961221/how-to-make-an-oval-in-css)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding border radius 100% / 50%

Comment: **Use below css to make an oval**

`.oval{
            border-radius: 50%;
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
        }`