# fabric.js : How to make an image in the shape of a oval with strokes shadow etc?

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have been trying to show a image as oval shape but no luck.

below is my code snippet, which works for circle but there are gaps when we are converting image from rectangle to ellipse

how can i add both rx, ry in html canvas?
this is how current code converts my rectangle image to ellipse, there are gaps in height & width they are not accurate.

sample output image:

[image]

```
fabric.util.loadImage(imageURL, function (img) {
      var oImg = new fabric.Image(img);


      if (slot.image_shape == "ellipse") {
        let shadow = (options && options.shadow) || {
          affectStroke: true,
        };
        const radius =
          oImg.width < oImg.height ? oImg.width / 2 : oImg.height / 2;
        oImg.set({
          clipTo: function (ctx) {
            return ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
          },
        });
      }
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with fabric.js, but if you want to create an oval shape from an image, why not use css? (border-radius, box-shadow) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26961221/how-to-make-an-oval-in-css

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I'm not aware of what fabric.js version you're actually using but from 2.4.0 onwards you can use the [clipPath](http://fabricjs.com/clippath-part1) property. In conjunction with the Ellipse class you can directly use an ellipsoidal shape as a mask - which let's you directly enter values for **rx** and **ry** instead of just a radius.

Here's an example:

```js
var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

fabric.Image.fromURL('https://picsum.photos/200/200', function(img) {
  img.set({
    hasControls: false,
    hasBorders: false,
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    clipPath: new fabric.Ellipse({
      rx: 100,
      ry: 50,
      originX: 'center',
      originY: 'center',
    }),
  });
  canvas.add(img);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.2.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400" class="canvas"></canvas>
```